# Toggle active date jQuery dateclicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I render my jQuery datepicker like so...

`HTML` :

`<div id="datepicker"></div>`

`JS` :

```
           $(function () {
            $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                            beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays,
                            dayNamesMin: [ "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S", "S" ],
                            duration: "slow",
                            showOtherMonths: true,
                            onSelect: function(date) {

                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        })
                       })
```

So when I select a date on the calendar it appends a class to the `td` element called `ui-datepicker-current-day` and the inner `a` element has `ui-state-active` added to it.

I'm trying to, so onClick of the element again, toggle it off. However, I can't get onClick events to trigger within the datepicker.

I can attach onClick events to other elements of `html` on the page. But anything within the jQuery UI datepicker, none of the click events trigger.

Has anyone any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have an javascript error (check you console) - it's a parse error. You didn't close parenthesis. That's why no onclick is working.

About your problem globally, try this thing:

```
$(function () {
    var previousValue = null;
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays,
        dayNamesMin: [ "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S", "S" ],
        duration: "slow",
        showOtherMonths: true,
        onSelect: function(date) {


            if (previousValue == $(this).val()) {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker('setDate', null);
            }
            previousValue = $(this).val();
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rafii/kgkpLakj/3/

The only problem is, when you're resetting date picker - it sets current date.

EDIT: add this (whole function in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rafii/kgkpLakj/4/)

in datepicker configuration:

```
defaultDate: null
```

and in onSelect function:

```
$('a.ui-state-active').removeClass('ui-state-active');
```

Comment: This is kind of what I was looking for. However, now it resets it back to the current day i'm on. So i'm on Septemeber I click the date picker date again to de-select it and it sends me back to June. I want it to just clear all the selected dates and keep me on the date i'm on

Comment: See my edit. Add
defaultDate: null

and also in the onSelect function
$('a.ui-state-active').removeClass('ui-state-active');